# rCannot Explicitly Call Operator or Accessor For Calls From Included Library

Tags: c#, microsoft-dynamics

I have imported the package "Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.2015 -Version 7.1.0.1085" using Nuget and I have no errors or warnings that it is not installed. However, code that is referencing the package such as

`entity.get.LogicalName()` in the context of `if (entity.get_LogicalName() == "account" || entity.get_LogicalName() == "contact")` gets the error  "cannot explicitly call operator or accessor."

I know this code works because it is actively deployed. I have inherited it and have taken it from a code repo that did not have any resource libraries so they need to be downloaded again.

Any help in resolving this is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to compile decompiled code?

Comment: I did decompile some code from an existing DLL but I was able to make this compile with a different version of this library.

Comment: @CodeCaster I do not understand how this is a duplicate because the code worked before. Why would I need to change the code now to work? Thanks!

Comment: Because the original code is `entity.LogicalName`, but you decompiled that and now are trying to compile `entity.get_LogicalName()`, which isn't valid C# for a property accessor. Change it to the former.